# Disabling predictive text for just a single language

Tags: keyboard, text-input, text-prediction

I am using three languages on my phone - English, Dutch and Lithuanian and predictive text on the English and the Dutch languages are all OK. What I am trying to achieve is to switch off predictive text for Lithuanian but the only way I've found to do this was to switch it off completely for all languages.

Predictive text for Lithuanian is a pain for me as the language uses some special characters like *ą, č, ė* or *ū* which reduces the limit of characters in an SMS message to 70 instead of 140 and which I can easily substitute with Latin equivalents like *a, c, e* and *u*.